# Append missing part

Tags: command-line, files

I have a file on my backup drive that is `foo.txt` (30 GiB).

I have a file on my regular drive that is `foo.txt` (60 GiB, first 30 GiB is guaranteed to be exactly the same).

How can I only append the missing part without recopying the whole file?

Maybe something with `dd` would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sync files there’s `rsync`, it has an `--append` option to “append data onto shorter files”:

```bsh
rsync --append /path/to/foo.txt /path/to/foo.txt
#              ^- original      ^- copy
```

#### Example run

Test scenario flagrantly copied from steeldriver’s answer – I added the `-P` and `-v` options for verbose output.

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M iflag=fullblock count=60 of=origfile
60+0 records in
60+0 records out
62914560 bytes (63 MB, 60 MiB) copied, 0.328983 s, 191 MB/s
$ dd if=origfile bs=1M iflag=fullblock count=30 of=newfile
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB, 30 MiB) copied, 0.0292976 s, 1.1 GB/s
$ cmp origfile newfile
cmp: EOF on newfile
$ rsync -Pv --append origfile newfile
origfile
     62,914,560 100%  365.47MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 31,465,039 bytes  received 35 bytes  20,976,716.00 bytes/sec
total size is 62,914,560  speedup is 2.00
$ cmp origfile newfile
$
```

Comment: Nice - I thought there *should* be a way to do it with `rsync`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `dd` - the trick is to choose both `bs` x `skip` and `obs` x `seek` equal to the **exact** required offset

Ex.

First lets generate a test file - I've chosen 60MiB rather than 60GiB for the sake of illustration:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M iflag=fullblock count=60 of=origfile
60+0 records in
60+0 records out
62914560 bytes (63 MB, 60 MiB) copied, 0.376846 s, 167 MB/s
```

Now lets copy exactly the first half of it - again using `dd` (though that's not required)

```
$ dd if=origfile bs=1M iflag=fullblock count=30 of=newfile
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB, 30 MiB) copied, 0.063891 s, 492 MB/s
```

Verify that they're different:

```
$ cmp origfile newfile
cmp: EOF on newfile after byte 31457280, in line 122106
```

Now let's copy from `origfile` to `newfile`, skipping the first `30` x `1M` blocks of both files:

```
$ dd if=origfile bs=1M iflag=fullblock skip=30 count=30 of=newfile seek=30
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
31457280 bytes (31 MB, 30 MiB) copied, 0.0632964 s, 497 MB/s
```

Finally, verify that the files are now identical:

```
$ cmp origfile newfile
$
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a huge file, but if it handles the size, you could use the `split` command to split the 60GB file into `file1` and `file2`.  Then use `cat` to put the parts you want back together.

Example:

```
split -n2 60Gfile
cat xab >> 30Gfile
```

`split -n2` splits the file in half and makes 2 files called `xaa` and `xab`

If this doesn't do what you want, read the split manual as the command has other options.

Comment: Now I know about another command. To future readers: `split -n 2/2 foo.txt` outputs second half of file to `stdout`; this is useful to pair with other commands. `--byte` option splits every n bytes.